# Можно ли передавать параметры в триггер?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Можно ли передавать параметры триггерам, как в процедурах и функциях?
Если да, то можно ли вызвать триггер явно с этими параметрами?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Can we pass parameters in triggers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35403852) от участника [@Gok](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5882342/gok)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/35403852

Answer (score 3):

Tриггер срабатывает при наступлении DML события на объекте БД, на котором определен триггер. Это событие нельзя вызвать явно, единственный способ - выполнить DML запрос.

Передача параметров не является частью определения триггера.

Одно из самых простых решений -- передать параметры в переменной сессии. Для этого, переменная сессии должна быть установленна до наступления события DML.

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
create table t (id int, memo varchar2(96), dt date)
/
create or replace package pack as
    type paramarr is table of varchar2 (32) index by varchar2 (8);
    params paramarr;
end;
/
create or replace trigger tnewtrig before insert on t for each row
begin 
    :new.memo := 'triggered by '||user||' with params: param1='||
        pack.params('param1')||' param2='||pack.params('param2');
    :new.dt := sysdate;
end;    
/
```

Запуск и результат:

```
exec pack.params := pack.paramarr ('param1' => 'val1', 'param2' => 'val2');

insert into t (id) values (1);

select * from t;

        ID MEMO             DT                 
---------- ---------------- -------------------
         1 triggered by ME  2021-06-25 11:49:36
           with params:                        
           param1=val1                         
           param2val2
```

**Важно:** следует учесть, что переменные сессии не транзакциональны, т.е. не следует в них хранить значения, подсчитанные в разных трнзакциях. При откате одной из транзакций, изменённое в этой транзакции заначение переменной сессии не откатится и по сути, станет недействительным.

Comment: *Одно из самых простых решений -- передать параметры в переменной сессии.* По-моему, использование сервисной таблицы - куда как более простое и очевидное решение. К тому же неподвластное куче неблагоприятных факторов, вроде обрыва/восстановления соединения. А главное - применимое и в отсутствие паков, из внешней stmt-based программы.

Comment: Да, ещё к тому же и не ограниченное одной DBMS.

Comment: @Akina Делал и так и так. Не думаю, что решение с  таблицами более простое или очевидное. О выборе решения можно говорить только имея требования конкретной бизнес задачи. Особенности бренда СУБД учтены в метках.